# Taylor approximation of exponential constraints

Tags: optimization, taylor-expansion, exponential-function, convex-optimization, second-order-cone-programming

I'm currently tackling an optimization problem that involves an exponential constraint, and I'm trying to apply the following technique to transform it into second-order cones. However, I'm struggling to grasp why the last two lines of equations are equivalent. Any insights or explanations on this would be greatly appreciated.
[image]

Comment: Looks like just a naive binomial expansion of $(1+t)^4$ in the last term. Why do you want to use this approximation? There are quite a few solvers which work directly with exponential cones.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I'm working on a large-scale optimization problem that current exponential cone solvers struggle to handle. My aim is to adapt this technique by employing a Taylor approximation at an even higher order (e.g., up to the 6th order instead of the 4th)

Comment: I doubt a bit if replacing  $N$ exponential cones with say $5N$ quadratic cones will improve the situation. Perhaps you can share more details of the problem and the solver's struggle to get more ideas. For example https://or.stackexchange.com/  could be a good forum for that. I am from Mosek, you are welcome to contact support as well. We are interested in hearing about big exponential cone problems.

Comment: Thank you so much for your input – it's a great point! I initially used Mosek to tackle the exponential cone problem. Basically I’m trying to solve a variation of the logistic regression, where the cone constraints originate from transforming the logistic loss function, along with some other problem-specific constraints. With a dataset of over 5,000 observations and 20 features, the solver's processing time extends to a few hours. Because of that I'm exploring potential reformulations/approximations that could enable a more efficient solution.

Comment: I'm nott an expert here but it was always my impression that the ML community regards conic optimization (perhaps rightly so) as a wrong tool for logistic regression because of the problem sizes, and that less accurate but faster gradient descent algorithms are preferred. That I really don't know and here we can't help. What I can offer is that if you send an email to Mosek support then we can look at the conic problems and at least estimate what is realistic and what is not.